# how to show toast message in not extend activity class

Tags: android

hi this is my helper class where i check internal connection and xml paersing and use this class to another activity  the problem is  when server connected is working fine but when server not responding or invalid  input code is blast   stop unexpectedly i find out asyntask to resolve this isse but my problem is how can i used AsyncTask in this code?  or how to show toast message if server not responding    error message Connection Error aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  is show on log but not show on toast what do i do  so my application not blast when server not respond? any idea?

```
 public class AgAppHelperMethods {

     private static final String LOG_TAG = null;

     private static AgAppHelperMethods instance = null;

     public static String varMobileNo;
     public static String varPinNo;
     String[][] xmlRespone = null;

     public static String getUrl() {
         String url = "https://demo.accessgroup.mobi/";
         return url;
     }

     public static String[][] AgAppXMLParser(String parUrl) {
         String _node, _element;
         String[][] xmlRespone = null;
         try {
             String url = AgAppHelperMethods.getUrl() + parUrl;
             URL finalUrl = new URL(url);
             DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
                 DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
             Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(finalUrl.openStream()));
             doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

             NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
             _node = new String();
             _element = new String();
             xmlRespone = new String[list.getLength()][2];

             for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                 Node value = list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0);
                 _node = list.item(i).getNodeName();
                 _element = value.getNodeValue();
                 xmlRespone[i][0] = _node;
                 xmlRespone[i][1] = _element;
             } //end for
         } //end try
         catch (Exception e) {
             // Toast.makeText(context, "error  server not responding " +  
             e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connection Error aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
             e);
         // Do something else, if wanted.
     }
     return xmlRespone;
 }
```

Comment: After seeing comments etc. I think you should start more simple. This is way above you. Read some fundamental books on programming.

Answer (score 6):

Create a global variable like:

```
Context mContext;
```

Then add a constructor to your class, in which you accept a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) parameter and assign it to mContext like:

```
public AgAppHelperMethods(Context context) {
      mContext = context;
}
```

Create an object in your Activity like:

```
AgAppHelperMethods helper = new AgAppHelperMethods(getBaseContext());
```

Finally, to show your Toast use:

```
 Toast.makeText(mContext, "error  server not responding " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: it try it this mesage come when do what u say 
The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type AgAppHelperMethods

Comment: if u dont mind RaghavSood  do u give me ur email address or skype id

Comment: @LastSumorai That part needs to be in your Activity.

Comment: I don't offer private support, sorry.

Comment: Context mContext;
  this global object crete in not activity class or   activity clas where i show  toast?

Comment: Put that as a global variable in your helper class. I've told you where every bit of that code goes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target your applicationContext in the toast,i can't see you doing that anywhere?
And you have outcommented the first line of your toast message?

Edit:
Also really really bad codestyle to catch exception e. You should try to narrow down which kind of exception it is that you want to catch.

Comment: i want to catch exception server not responding eror or invalid user id pasword exception

Answer (score 1):

Create myToast method in your application class, Like

```
public void myToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and add the following code to your class,

```
private MyApplication application;
public AgAppHelperMethods(Context context) {
  application = (MyApplication)context.getApplication();
}
```

Finally, call myToast method, where you want, like

```
applicaion.myToast("msg you want to show");
```

Note: replace MyApplication with your application class

I have not tested, but this may work for u.

Comment: sir fi u dont mind can i sent u full code by mail? so u can just run and easily dignose problem?

Comment: what u mean by application class? u mean a  activity clas or agapphelpermethod class?

Comment: create a class by extending "Application", its called as an application class