# Android Toast Error

Tags: android, asynchronous, toast

I am receiving a `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1` error.

I have not created a Async Task I simply called the code below.

I am calling the following from a class that connects to the network:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Connection Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`context` has been passed through in the constructor from the `MainActivity`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Could you post the code that the Toast command is in? Is it in an Activity, a service, a thread .... all this will help people answer you. You may not have created an AsyncTask, but what have you created?

Comment: can you show whole code...??

Comment: and the whole log output please?

Comment: where you are trying to show Toast inside doInBackground? if yes then move it in onPostExecute method

Comment: write like this Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "xyz click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: It is not in an activity. Just a helper class. so i think that falls under a service.

Comment: @user1331971 : how u are creating object of Network class?

Comment: calling this from my main activity class:  ` netConnection = new Network(new Network.OnMessageReceived() {
    @Override
    // here the messageReceived method is implemented
    public void messageReceived(String message) {
     // this method calls the onProgressUpdate
     publishProgress(message);
    }
   }, getBaseContext());`

Comment: pass activity context to your helper class and the use the activity context to display toast

Comment: is that not what I am already doing?

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964951/how-to-show-toast-mesage-in-not-extend-activity-class) if it helps

Comment: @Zapnologica : no need to try just see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make following changes for showing Toast from `Network` class(non Activity class) :

**Step:1** Pass Activity Context to Network class instead of `getBaseContext()` :

```
netConnection = new Network(new Network.OnMessageReceived() { 
            @Override 
            // here the messageReceived method is implemented 
           public void messageReceived(String message) { 
                 // this method calls the onProgressUpdate 
                 publishProgress(message); 
           } 
     },Your_Current_Activity_Name.this);
```

**Step 2:** use `runOnUiThread` for showing Toast from Network class :

```
 public boolean connect() {
 //....your code..
 Activity activity = (Activity) context;
 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //show your Toast here..
       Toast.makeText(context,"Connection Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
 //....your code..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Will try that now, Looks promising.

Comment: Great answer! I use this to display a Toast from an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

What a strange answers here :)

First guy want you to extend `Network` class from [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#q=getbasecontext), second tells you that you have not got Android SDK :)

You just need to send correct `Context` object to your `Network` object, you need to send `Context` object from [`getBaseContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext%28%29) method, because this context object is correct for [`Toast`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) messages ([here you can read explanation about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605459/android-why-must-use-getbasecontext-instead-of-this)).

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: getApplicationContext() does not work, eclipse says create the method.

Comment: Android SDk is installed and all other aspects of the app work correctly. Does getApplicationContext() not only work if the class extends activity?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Connection Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: getBaseContext() does not work, it says create method 'getbaseContext'

Comment: @user1331971 Can you change `public class Network` to 
`public class Network extends Activity`?

Comment: @user1331971 Then you can use mine, or Nirav's solution

Comment: @user1331971: You have to extend Activity

Comment: How will that affect the functionality of the class? This class is not intended to be an activity, the main activity calls the network class. i just want this class to say connected or connection failed when called. So it must display the toast on the activity that called it.

Comment: @user1331971 Only 1 way to find out isn't it :p

Comment: @user1331971 : after investigating your class i think u are trying to show Toast from background Thread ? then u will need to use runOnUiThread for showing Toast